# Go modules: checksum mismatch

Tags: go, go-modules

I recently started using modules in Go, but I frequently encounter issues where everything works fine on one machine, but a checksum mismatch is encountered when building the codebase on another machine.

The issue always concerns the same third party dependency (github.com/ericlagergren/decimal):

```
go: verifying github.com/ericlagergren/decimal@v0.0.0-20181231230500-73749d4874d5: checksum mismatch
    downloaded: h1:HQGCJNlqt1dUs/BhtEKmqWd6LWS+DWYVxi9+Jo4r0jE=
    go.sum:     h1:x4oNpFLLl+8l+iLgksNHzZewTS0SKp6m0hlLwzXRbqA=
```

I've tried various things: removing & regenerating `go.sum`, upgrading Go itself to the latest patch version and removing the dependency from `go.mod` but nothing seems to fix this issue.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Which version of Go are you using? There's a good chance you're running into the aftermath of the `1.11.2 -> 1.11.4`:

- https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27093
- https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27925
- https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29278

Which still isn't completely resolved. Remember that `go mod` is still in development, so things like this will probably happen up and until 1.13.

Be sure to read up on minor releases for Go, and how these things *can* happen: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/MinorReleases

> TL;DR - Upgrade Go

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, I was on 11.1 (I assume that's 11.1.0). I already something about issues in earlier versions of Go, so yesterday I updated to 11.1.4 locally. This didn't seem to change the problem: however I think that on platforms like Heroku the older go 11.1.0 is still used.

Comment: I changed the settings on Heroku to use 1.11.4 and it seems my problem is solved. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 67):

You can run `go clean -modcache`, delete go.sum and then `go mod tidy` which will re-download all deps with the correct checksum (this updates the pkg cache in `$GOPATH/pkg/mod/`).

To update `vendor/` folder run: `go mod vendor`.

Comment: This fixed it for me. After running those commands, I ended up with different hashes in my `go.sum` file. I commited that to version control and magically my CI cheered up :-)

Comment: I have no idea how that happened but those commands fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Probably a history rewrite commit happened in that repo that changed the checksum.

Comment: I followed the step and cleaned the `-modcache`. Then I wasted my 1 hours downloading the dependencies again. :( There needs to be a better solution.

Comment: @MarufTuhin I think you can search the cache folder for your version in the `$GOPATH/pkg/mod` and delete it.

Comment: to avoid long download time, one could just remove checksum mismatching mod entries from `go.sum` and run `go mod tidy`, this will just update the checksum of that module!

Comment: `go mod tidy` - it doesn`t delete older packages

Comment: @Vladimir  `go mod tidy` does not delete anything from the package cache, however `go clean -modcache` does, the tidy part only checks your go.mod file and your go files imports and tries to reconcile the dependencies. Also `go mod tidy` does not update the `vendor` folder, for that run `go mod vendor`

Comment: @AlexEfimov `go clean -modcache` do nothing with **checksum mismatch** issues.

Comment: Hmm, strange, it did until now for me. Try doing a `rm -rf $GOPATH/pkg/mod/` or manually deleting those files. Which version of go are you using?

Comment: @AlexEfimov `go version go1.13.4 linux/amd64` so why your `rm -rf $GOPATH/pkg/mod/` is better than `sed '/^github.com\/ericlagergren\/decimal@/d' ./go.sum > temp.txt && mv temp.txt go.sum` ?

Comment: didn't work for me. had to remove go.sum file before run go mod tidy

Comment: I had 4 checksums for one module that was hosted in bitbucket (with dash seperated additional numbers in 3 checksums). I manually deleted the additional 3 checksums, ran ```go mod tidy```

Comment: Didn't solve the issue

Answer (score 26):

1. remove go.sum : rm go.sum
2. regenerate go.sum : go mod tidy

Comment: Makes sense, I thought about that too, ran it, and ... it did not work, same error =S Solution: do the same for other projects included as a dependency which in turn were having shared libraries that were causing the initial error

Comment: Yes, this will fix the problem, but this ignores the whole purpose of `go.sum`. What if the downloaded package was replaced in the source repository and now contains malicious code?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem because of the GOPROXY, and the problem was solved by changing the proxy address.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem using 1.12.8 and no cache cleaning would help. Turns out I am still locked in the middle of GOPATH and the Mod world. I found a flag in another post ([How do I migrate from Dep to Go Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55664630/how-do-i-migrate-from-dep-to-go-modules)) that did the trick for me.

```
go run -mod=vendor main.go
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I updated the go version and removed the imports from go.mod and removed all entries from go.sum and ran go mo tidy, which downloaded all the dependencies without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete your package from the **go.sum** file.
If you run from terminal mode, using CI/CD or Dockerfile you can use that **sh** command:

```
sed '/^github.com\/ericlagergren\/decimal@/d' ./go.sum > temp.txt && mv temp.txt go.sum
```

Which does:

- **sed** - unix application
- **'/^** - starts line from
- github.com\/hyperledger\/fabric v1.4.4 - your package name (actually RegEX line, shield **/** with **\**)
- **/d'** - means delete line
- **go.sum** - our golang sum file
- **> temp.txt** - save output to temporary file
- **mv temp.txt go.sum** - rewrite our go.sum with temporary file

P.S.: `go mod tidy` - only removes unused packages and add new versions. But **it doesn`t delete olders**.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
$ go get sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.14.1
go: downloading sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime v0.14.1
verifying sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.14.1/go.mod: checksum mismatch
        downloaded: h1:GaRkrY8a7UZF0kqFFbUKG7n9ICiTY5T55P1RiE3UZlU=
        go.sum:     h1:G7mAYYxgmS0lVkHyy2hEOLQCFB0DlQFTMLWggykrydY=
```

remove the relate file on the mod cache

```
# rm -rf ~/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.14.1/
# rm ~/go/pkg/mod/cache/download/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/@v/v0.14.1.zip
# rm ~/go/pkg/mod/cache/download/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/@v/v0.14.1.info
# rm ~/go/pkg/mod/cache/download/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/@v/v0.14.1.mod
# rm ~/go/pkg/mod/cache/download/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/@v/v0.14.1.lock
# rm ~/go/pkg/mod/cache/download/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/@v/v0.14.1.ziphash
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also check / set the GOPROXY to prevent such cases when updating
`go env GOPROXY`
`go env -w GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct`

this with `go clean -modcache` and `go mod tidy` should fix the issue

EDIT: [source](https://goproxy.io/sumdb/sum.golang.org/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my teammate committed a different sum in the `go.sum` for the problematic package and all I had to do was to revert the `go.sum` to its previous state.

Which made a lot of sense in my case because the package I was having problems with hadn't been changed for years.