# How do I migrate from Dep to Go Modules

Tags: go, godeps, go-modules, govendor

I'm currently using Dep and would like to start using Go modules.

How do I migrate?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Migrating from Dep to Go Modules is very easy.

1. Run `go version` and make sure you're using Go version 1.11 or later.
2. Move your code outside of GOPATH or set `export GO111MODULE=on`.
3. `go mod init [module path]`: This will import dependencies from Gopkg.lock.
4. `go mod tidy`: This will remove unnecessary imports, and add indirect ones.
5. (Optional) Delete your vendor folder (`rm -rf vendor/` or move to trash)
6. `go build`: Do a test build to see if it works.
7. `rm -f Gopkg.lock Gopkg.toml`: Delete the obsolete files used for Dep.

Go has imported my dependencies from Dep by reading the `Gopkg.lock` file and also created a `go.mod` file.

If you want to keep your vendor folder:

7. Run `go mod vendor` to copy your dependencies into the vendor folder.
8. Run `go build -mod=vendor` to ensure `go build` uses your vendor folder.

Comment: After I ran these when I try to build, I am getting this error `clang: error: unable to read SDK settings for '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk'`

Comment: @Surya try updating your CommandLineTools: `xcode-select --install`

Comment: Yes did that and did this too xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/ Still no luck @Nicholas

Comment: Be cautious with step 5. If your repo has vendor folder, it quite possibly contains some stuff unavailable otherwise

Comment: Worked for me in 2023

Answer (score 5):

To add to @Nicholas answer's:

[Here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-to-define-a-module) is from the offical golang documenation:

To create a go.mod for an existing project:

1. Navigate to the root of the module's source tree outside of GOPATH:

```sh
$ export GO111MODULE=on                         # manually active module mode
$ cd $GOPATH/src/<project path>                 # e.g., cd $GOPATH/src/you/hello
```

2. Create the initial module definition and write it to the go.mod file:

```sh
$ go mod init
```

This step converts from any existing [dep](https://github.com/golang/dep) Gopkg.lock file or [from any of the other nine total supported dependency formats](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/cmd/go/internal/modconv/?m=all#pkg-variables), adding require statements to match the existing configuration.

3. Build the module. When executed from the root directory of a module, the ./... pattern matches all the packages within the current module. go build will automatically add missing or unconverted dependencies as needed to satisfy imports for this particular build invocation:

```sh
$ go build ./...
```

4. Test the module as configured to ensure that it works with the selected versions:

```sh
$ go test ./...
```

5. (Optional) Run the tests for your module plus the tests for all direct and indirect dependencies to check for incompatibilities:

```sh
$ go test all
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to upgrade to modules.

- Remove the Gopkg.toml and Gopkg.lock

  `rm Gopkg.*`
- Initialise the Go modules

  `GO111MODULE=on go mod init`
- Run go mod tidy to pull all the indirect modules and remove unused modules

  `GO111MODULE=on go mod tidy`
- Run build to ensure everything works fine

  `go build`

Tip in case you face few modules not found then manually update the modules tag in go.mod file.