# Setting up golang project in VS code

Tags: go

I want to clone a git golang project and setup in VS code in windows.Tried to research but havn't been able to figure out. I am using DEP dependency management.

Can someone please help with end to end steps?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of tips:

- use the latest 1.13.1 Go
- [Convert your dep dependencies to Go modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55664631/6309) (that way, you don't depend on a GOPATH, but you can import your project from wherever you have cloned it)
- Add a root folder of your project to your VSCode workspace
- Make sure you have the [VSCode-Go plugin installed](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go)

From there, you can start working on the sources.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to help you with how i was able to setup a golang project with a similar set of parameters :

Setting up project:
1)Install Git in VS code.
2) Clone the project from Git repository into a folder(e.g. MyGolangProject)
3) Open command line  or VS terminal and execute :  dep ensure 
e.g. 
{Path}\MyGolangProject\src{DirPath} >  dep ensure
Note : This would generate a Gopkg.lock file(locks the version of the packages EXCEPT the version should be maintained in the Gopkg.toml) and a vendor folder(vendoring all dependencies) based on our Gopkg.toml file(which contains several types of rule declarations that govern dep's behavior)
4) Set the  env variables separately from console or from a bat file if any.
5) Run the main.go file →
{Path}\MyGolangProject\src{DirPath} > go run main.go
6)Test the project

Environment variables to be set :
1) GOPATH -->The GOPATH environment variable is used to specify directories outside of $GOROOT that contain the source for Go projects and their binaries.
e.g. in the example above, GOPATH will be set to {Path}\MyGolangProject
2) GOROOT → Download the go zip file and extract it into the directory of your choice (e.g. C:\Apps\GO)
set the GOROOT environment variable to your chosen path {Path}\GO ,say, e.g. C:\Apps\GO
3) Path →
a) Add the bin subdirectory of your Go root (for example, {Path}\GO\bin) to your PATH environment variable.
b) Download DEP(Dependency management) ,(and other tools if any e.g. Mockgen for testing) into say C:\Apps\GoDependencies
The folder containing dep.exe ( and mockgen.exe if used) to your PATH environment variable(i.e. C:\Apps\GoDependencies)

I hope it helps