# go get mongo-driver errors: verifying module: checksum mismatch

Tags: mongodb, go

I am getting errors when I ran, using `go version go1.15.7 darwin/amd64`

`go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver`

```
go: downloading go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver v1.4.5
go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver: go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.4.5: verifying module: checksum mismatch
    downloaded: h1:z4/YQzLTxI+ymcrS//Wc2JBn2b9ojvpVH3BaYT8rqUc=
    sum.golang.org: h1:TLtO+iD8krabXxvY1F1qpBOHgOxhLWR7XsT7kQeRmMY=


SECURITY ERROR
This download does NOT match the one reported by the checksum server.
The bits may have been replaced on the origin server, or an attacker may
have intercepted the download attempt.

For more information, see 'go help module-auth'.
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Funny to see that the same error occurs again in the latest version 1.13.0 of that driver. I think they mess up the versioning from time to time. I also see no way to solve that problem other than choosing a different (not messed up) version. I deleted all caches on my machine but still I get different checksum than e.g. out GitLab ci.

Answer (score 0):

Before you apply this, you might want to check why the checksum is different. There might be a security issue and someone might try to inject malicious code into the dependency. That is what checksums are there to prevent. They make sure the checksum of the package you are downloading is the same you downloaded earlier (if the version is the same).

#### Solution

Delete the `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver` related checksum from `go.sum` file in your repository.

If that does not help a cleanup of your modules cache might help:

```
go clean -modcache
```

Comment: I only have 3 things in my go.mod right now: `github.com/golang/protobuf v1.4.3`
 `google.golang.org/grpc v1.35.0`
 `google.golang.org/protobuf v1.25.0` 
I dont see anything related to `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver` in go.sum,
I also tried `go clean -modcache`, still does not work

Comment: did you try the `go clean -modcache`?

Comment: When I call a `go get` it works and adds this checksum to my go.sum file: `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver v1.4.5 h1:TLtO+iD8krabXxvY1F1qpBOHgOxhLWR7XsT7kQeRmMY=`

Comment: Here another thread on a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54133789/go-modules-checksum-mismatch It mostly suggests the same I did. Not sure why it is not working for you.

Comment: Or maybe you are still using GOPATH a bit? Maybe an old version of `mongo-driver` is still in your `GOPATH/src` folder?

Comment: I just succesfully downloaded it with `go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo@v1.4.4`, seems like without specifying the version number, it tries to download 1.4.5, which has the problem

Comment: This seems to be an issue with version 1.4.5 specifically: https://jira.mongodb.org/projects/GODRIVER/issues/GODRIVER-1851?filter=allopenissues